# How to access Modbus TCP/IP Register 4XXXXX.1 in C#?

Tags: c#, modbus

I need to access those register 4XXXXX.1, 4XXXXX.2 and 4XXXXX.3...etc etc

I try to use to use modscan64, I can only enter number in XXXXX as whole number, I am not able to enter address as decimal in my register.

this is my current C# method for read register, I got exception when I try to read decimal number in address. I am using EasyModbus library.

```
 public int[] ReadHoldingRegisters(int startingAddress, int quantity)
        {
            if (debug) StoreLogData.Instance.Store("FC3 (Read Holding Registers from Master device), StartingAddress: "+ startingAddress+", Quantity: " +quantity, System.DateTime.Now);
            transactionIdentifierInternal++;
            if (serialport != null)
                if (!serialport.IsOpen)
                {
                    if (debug) StoreLogData.Instance.Store("SerialPortNotOpenedException Throwed", System.DateTime.Now);
                    throw new EasyModbus.Exceptions.SerialPortNotOpenedException("serial port not opened");
                }
            if (tcpClient == null & !udpFlag & serialport == null)
            {
                if (debug) StoreLogData.Instance.Store("ConnectionException Throwed", System.DateTime.Now);
                throw new EasyModbus.Exceptions.ConnectionException("connection error");
            }
            if (startingAddress > 65535 | quantity >125)
            {
                if (debug) StoreLogData.Instance.Store("ArgumentException Throwed", System.DateTime.Now);
                throw new ArgumentException("Starting address must be 0 - 65535; quantity must be 0 - 125");
            }
            int[] response;
            this.transactionIdentifier = BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)transactionIdentifierInternal);
            this.protocolIdentifier = BitConverter.GetBytes((int) 0x0000);
            this.length = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)0x0006);
            this.functionCode = 0x03;
            this.startingAddress = BitConverter.GetBytes(startingAddress);
            this.quantity = BitConverter.GetBytes(quantity);
            Byte[] data = new byte[]{   this.transactionIdentifier[1],
                            this.transactionIdentifier[0],
                            this.protocolIdentifier[1],
                            this.protocolIdentifier[0],
                            this.length[1],
                            this.length[0],
                            this.unitIdentifier,
                            this.functionCode,
                            this.startingAddress[1],
                            this.startingAddress[0],
                            this.quantity[1],
                            this.quantity[0],
                            this.crc[0],
                            this.crc[1]
            };
            crc = BitConverter.GetBytes(calculateCRC(data, 6, 6));
            data[12] = crc[0];
            data[13] = crc[1];
            if (serialport != null)
            {
                dataReceived = false;
                bytesToRead = 5 + 2 * quantity;
//                serialport.ReceivedBytesThreshold = bytesToRead;
                serialport.Write(data, 6, 8);
                if (debug)
                {
                    byte [] debugData = new byte[8];
                    Array.Copy(data, 6, debugData, 0, 8);
                    if (debug) StoreLogData.Instance.Store("Send Serial-Data: "+BitConverter.ToString(debugData) ,System.DateTime.Now);                 
                }
               if (SendDataChanged != null)
                {
                    sendData = new byte[8];
                    Array.Copy(data, 6, sendData, 0, 8);
                    SendDataChanged(this);

                }
                data = new byte[2100];
                readBuffer = new byte[256];

                DateTime dateTimeSend = DateTime.Now;
                byte receivedUnitIdentifier = 0xFF;
                while (receivedUnitIdentifier != this.unitIdentifier & !((DateTime.Now.Ticks - dateTimeSend.Ticks) > TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond * this.connectTimeout))
                {
                    while (dataReceived == false & !((DateTime.Now.Ticks - dateTimeSend.Ticks) > TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond * this.connectTimeout))
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);  
                    data = new byte[2100];
                    Array.Copy(readBuffer, 0, data, 6, readBuffer.Length);

                    receivedUnitIdentifier = data[6];
                }
                if (receivedUnitIdentifier != this.unitIdentifier)
                    data = new byte[2100];
                else
                    countRetries = 0;
            }
            else if (tcpClient.Client.Connected | udpFlag)
            {
                if (udpFlag)
                {
                    UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
                    IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port);
                    udpClient.Send(data, data.Length-2, endPoint);
                    portOut = ((IPEndPoint)udpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint).Port;
                    udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
                    endPoint = new IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), portOut);
                    data = udpClient.Receive(ref endPoint);
                }
                else
                {
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length-2);
                    if (debug)
                {
                    byte [] debugData = new byte[data.Length-2];
                    Array.Copy(data, 0, debugData, 0, data.Length-2);
                    if (debug) StoreLogData.Instance.Store("Send ModbusTCP-Data: "+BitConverter.ToString(debugData) ,System.DateTime.Now);                  
                }
                    if (SendDataChanged != null)
                    {
                        sendData = new byte[data.Length-2];
                        Array.Copy(data, 0, sendData, 0, data.Length-2);
                        SendDataChanged(this);

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("The data I get is " + BitConverter.ToString(data));

                    data = new Byte[256];
                    int NumberOfBytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    if (ReceiveDataChanged != null)
                    {
                        receiveData = new byte[NumberOfBytes];
                        Array.Copy(data, 0, receiveData, 0, NumberOfBytes);
                        if (debug) StoreLogData.Instance.Store("Receive ModbusTCP-Data: " + BitConverter.ToString(receiveData), System.DateTime.Now);
                        ReceiveDataChanged(this);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (data[7] == 0x83 & data[8] == 0x01)
            {
                if (debug) StoreLogData.Instance.Store("FunctionCodeNotSupportedException Throwed", System.DateTime.Now);
                throw new EasyModbus.Exceptions.FunctionCodeNotSupportedException("Function code not supported by master");
            }
            if (data[7] == 0x83 & data[8] == 0x02)
            {
                if (debug) StoreLogData.Instance.Store("StartingAddressInvalidException Throwed", System.DateTime.Now);
                throw new EasyModbus.Exceptions.StartingAddressInvalidException("Starting address invalid or starting address + quantity invalid");
            }
            if (data[7] == 0x83 & data[8] == 0x03)
            {
                if (debug) StoreLogData.Instance.Store("QuantityInvalidException Throwed", System.DateTime.Now);
                throw new EasyModbus.Exceptions.QuantityInvalidException("quantity invalid");
            }
            if (data[7] == 0x83 & data[8] == 0x04)
            {
                if (debug) StoreLogData.Instance.Store("ModbusException Throwed", System.DateTime.Now);
                throw new EasyModbus.Exceptions.ModbusException("error reading");
            }
            if (serialport != null)
            {
            crc = BitConverter.GetBytes(calculateCRC(data, (ushort)(data[8]+3), 6));
                if ((crc[0] != data[data[8]+9] | crc[1] != data[data[8]+10])& dataReceived)
                {
                    if (debug) StoreLogData.Instance.Store("CRCCheckFailedException Throwed", System.DateTime.Now);
                    if (NumberOfRetries <= countRetries)
                    {
                        countRetries = 0;
                        throw new EasyModbus.Exceptions.CRCCheckFailedException("Response CRC check failed");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        countRetries++;
                        return ReadHoldingRegisters(startingAddress, quantity);
                    }
                }
                else if (!dataReceived)
                {
                    if (debug) StoreLogData.Instance.Store("TimeoutException Throwed", System.DateTime.Now);
                    if (NumberOfRetries <= countRetries)
                    {
                        countRetries = 0;
                        throw new TimeoutException("No Response from Modbus Slave");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        countRetries++;
                        return ReadHoldingRegisters(startingAddress, quantity);
                    }


                }
            }


            response = new int[quantity];
            for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
            {
                byte lowByte;
                byte highByte;
                highByte = data[9+i*2];
                lowByte = data[9+i*2+1];

                data[9+i*2] = lowByte;
                data[9+i*2+1] = highByte;

                response[i] = BitConverter.ToInt16(data,(9+i*2));
            }           
            return (response);          
        }
```

Comment: The Modbus protocol defines registers as whole numbers. If you are trying to read a certain bit from an input or holding register, you'll have to read the entire 16 bit register first.

Comment: then how to read the first one bit?

Comment: bit = (register & bitmask) >> bitnumber

Comment: `bit = ((register & bitmask) != 0);`

Answer (score 2):

The modbus specification provides an addressing prefix. 4XXXXX means you need to contact Holding Registers. That is, you need function 3 (read holding registers) with the usual address, without "4" at the start.
However, you write about 4XXXXX.1 - such a record usually says that you need bit number 2 of holding register with the address XXXXX

Answer (score 0):

When you read a register at XXXXX, you have a 16-bit value.

Using the built-in tools you can do the following:

```
var register = client.ReadHoldingRegisters(XXXXX, 1);
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(register);
BitArray ba = new BitArray(bytes);
```

`ba` now contains the bits of the specified register, accessible like an array. Note that you may need to swap the byte order or do some other data massaging to get what you need, but this should get you going.

Hope that helps.